# Airflow: How to run a task on multiple workers

Tags: celery, airflow, celery-task, airflow-scheduler

I have just set up airflow with celery executor and here is a skeleton of my DAG

```
dag = DAG('dummy_for_testing', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='test_queue',
    dag=dag)

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_host',
    bash_command='hostname >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='local_queue',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_uptime',
    bash_command='uptime >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='local_queue',
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t3)
t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

I have 2 workers. One of them runs only one queue called `local_queue` and the other runs two queues called `local_queue,test_queue`

I want to run task 1 on just 1 machine, but task 2 and 3 on both machines. i.e on worker 1 running just local_queue, t2 and t3 should run and on worker 2 running both local_queue and test_queue all 3 (t1,t2 and t3) should run.
Total number of task runs should be 5.

However, when i run this, only 3 tasks are run.
1) print_date is run for worker 2 (which is correct)
2) print_host is run for worker 1 only (incorrect. Should run for both workers) and
3) print_uptime is run for worker 2 only(also incorrect. Should run for both workers)

Can you please guide me on how to set this up so that 5 tasks are run. In production, i want to manage machines by grouping them into queues and for all machines having QUEUE_A -> do X and all machines having QUEUE_B -> do Y etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having one worker work 2 queues, have each worker work one queue.
So the worker commands should look like this:

```
airflow worker -q test_queue
airflow worker -q local_queue
```

Then have two of the same task, but in different queus.

```py
dag = DAG('dummy_for_testing', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='test_queue',
    dag=dag)

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_host',
    bash_command='hostname >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='local_queue',
    dag=dag)

t3_2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_host_2',
    bash_command='hostname >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='test_queue',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_uptime',
    bash_command='uptime >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='local_queue',
    dag=dag)

t2_2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_uptime_2',
    bash_command='uptime >> /tmp/dag_output.log',
    queue='test_queue',
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t3)
t2.set_upstream(t3_2)
t2.set_upstream(t1)

t2_2.set_upstream(t3)
t2_2.set_upstream(t3_2)
t2_2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Comment: This is OK if I have 2 hosts. What about having 10+ hosts or 100? I'm thinking that making tasks for each host can get error prone. If i have to add a host to this DAG setup, then I would prefer not to touch a running DAG, instead use queue names as a sort of logical grouping?

Comment: Airflow doesn't work like that. What if your task fails on one host but not the other? What happens when you need to view logs? Viewing logs is on a per task basis so what logs are you looking at: host 9 or host 10?

You can create these tasks in for loops while iterating an array of queues, that way if you add a new worker then you just add a new queue to the array at the top of the DAG.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you. I think i can also tie the queue name to the hostname of the worker. Is it possible for me to store worker definitions in a DB? then use a for loop on the resultset to create tasks on the fly? Will airflow update these DAGs on its own?

Comment: You can do that, but it will probably lower the scheduler performance (especially when you have a lot of dags doing this). The scheduler will process dag files frequently, so if it has to reach out to a DB every time it tries to see what your dag looks like, that can add up to a lot of database calls. On the other hand, the dags are parsed frequently, so the scheduler will see quickly any changes you have made. See scheduler settings: min_file_process_interval, max_threads for tuning dag parsing.